# It is not possible to send an image in an array of bytes to the database in blob format

Tags: c#, mysql, image, xamarin.forms

When sending an image in an array of bytes via a mysql request, I get an error: "Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down".
Here is my code:

```
byte[] imgfile;
var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = $"xamarin.{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss")}.jpg"
            });
imgfile = File.ReadAllBytes(photo.FullPath);
img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(photo.FullPath);
_connection.Open();
MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into acceptedapplications (Image) values(@Image)", _connection);;
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", imgfile);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
_connection.Close();
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help or not but I'd suggest ALWAYS using `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` and explicitly specifying the data type and, if applicable, the size.

Comment: Try Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = imgfile; and put some usings on Connection and SqlCommand.

Comment: You should use a web api to connect to backend services and not open a connection to DB from the mobile app itself. It's more secure and you will have a better control over the input/output